# Swift with Nested Json - Accessing Keys that are Not Strings

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to access keys in my API request (Nested Json) in Swift but the issue I'm having is that some of the keys in the `NSDictionary` are `Strings` with `"` and some keys don't have `"`.  The keys that don't have `"` (not strings) I can not access.

What I would like is to have all the keys in the `NSDictionary` be a `String` or `NSString` so that I can access the data.

Output from API server.

API data as JSON Sting

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"joe","last_name":"blow","email":"joeblow@test.com","api_authtoken":"qtgfLxuzaEJoJoLkZjdWt","authtoken_expiry":"2015-11-19T06:12:45.000Z","avatar_file_name":"1-1447697130.jpg","avatar_content_type":"image/png","avatar_file_size":516066,"avatar_updated_at":"2015-11-16T18:05:30.000Z","uid":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"address":null,"city":null,"state":null,"country":null,"postal_code":null,"phone_number":null,"belt":null,"fbid":null,"badges":[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"badge_type_id":1,"created_at":"2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z","updated_at":"2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z","badge_url":"http://newappy-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/badges/badge1.png"},{"id":2,"user_id":1,"badge_type_id":2,"created_at":"2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z","updated_at":"2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z","badge_url":"http://newappy-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/badges/badge2.png"},{"id":3,"user_id":1,"badge_type_id":3,"created_at":"2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z","updated_at":"2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z","badge_url":"http://newappy-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/badges/badge3.png"},{"id":4,"user_id":1,"badge_type_id":4,"created_at":"2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z","updated_at":"2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z","badge_url":"http://newappy-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/badges/badge4.png"}]}
```

Convert the API Data into a `NSDictionary`

```
let responseDict = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
            options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
```

The corresponding `NSDictionary` is as follows:

```
PRINTING NSDICTIONARY = {
address = "<null>";
"api_authtoken" = qtgfLxuzaEJoJoLkZjdWt;
"authtoken_expiry" = "2015-11-19T06:12:45.000Z";
"avatar_content_type" = "image/png";
"avatar_file_name" = "1-1447697130.jpg";
"avatar_file_size" = 516066;
"avatar_updated_at" = "2015-11-16T18:05:30.000Z";
badges =     (
            {
        "badge_type_id" = 1;
        "badge_url" = "http://newappy-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/badges/badge1.png";
        "created_at" = "2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z";
        id = 1;
        "updated_at" = "2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "badge_type_id" = 2;
        "badge_url" = "http://newappy-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/badges/badge2.png";
        "created_at" = "2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z";
        id = 2;
        "updated_at" = "2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "badge_type_id" = 3;
        "badge_url" = "http://newappy-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/badges/badge3.png";
        "created_at" = "2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z";
        id = 3;
        "updated_at" = "2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "badge_type_id" = 4;
        "badge_url" = "http://newappy-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/badges/badge4.png";
        "created_at" = "2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z";
        id = 4;
        "updated_at" = "2015-11-18T17:34:43.000Z";
        "user_id" = 1;
    }
);
belt = "<null>";
city = "<null>";
country = "<null>";
email = "joeblow@test.com";
fbid = "<null>";
"first_name" = joe;
id = 1;
"last_name" = blow;
latitude = "<null>";
longitude = "<null>";
"phone_number" = "<null>";
"postal_code" = "<null>";
state = "<null>";
uid = "<null>";
```

}

What I would like to do is iterate over the "badges" data in json.

I access the badges data like so:

```
dictionary.objectForKey("badges")
```

However I not getting the data.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you iterate over `dictionary.keys` and print out what type of object `badges` is? Alternatively, if this is JSON, then it should be string key anyway, and you should have a look at the server side of that API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `badges` key contains an array of dictionaries, therefore you should use:

```
let badges = dictionary.objectForKey("badges") as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Since `objectForKey:` returns `AnyObject?` we can use it to construct array of dictionaries with `String` as a key and `AnyObject` as a values. When you get the array you can iterate through it and get values you need.

I would suggest moving from Objective C `NSDictionary` type to Swift native `Dictionary`. That would enable you to use subscripts and deal with your code in an easier fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Said was few minutes faster than me. I was just writing example of how to accomplish it:

**Swift 1.2**

```
if let
    jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonPath),
    json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String: AnyObject]
{
    if let badges = json["badges"] as? [AnyObject]{
        for badge in badges{
            println(badge)
        }

    }
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath as NSString // it needs be NSString, Swift String doesn't have stringByAppendingPathComponent method
let jsonPath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.json")


do{
    if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonPath){
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
        if let badges = json["badges"] as? [AnyObject]{
            for badge in badges{
                print(badge)
                //or process it in any other way
            }

        }

    }
}catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```